# Yahoo Finance Data Errors

Tags: database, python-2.7, information-retrieval, yahoo-finance, quantitative-finance

A Python program using Yahoo Finance has recently stopped working properly because the data is inaccurate. Price data for multiple stocks has been replaced by zeros in date range 10/16 - 11/3. I initially saw this when I debugged and then when I went to the yahoo finance URLS for those stocks I confirmed the error.

Examples:

- https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/PSCT/history
- https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/VPU/history

Why might this be? Any suggestions to fix this or retrieve this data from an alternative source?

Comment: [This is being discussed on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358883/1415724).

Comment: Weird, it probably is somehow related to Yahoo discontinuing their API. However, I cannot find another instance of the actual stock data being corrupted/replaced by 0's...I don't understand why this would happen

Comment: I have a ticket going with yahoo on this issue.  See this url: https://forums.yahoo.net/t5/Yahoo-Finance-help/Missing-OCTOBER-Historical-Data-NAV/td-p/392162/highlight/false/page/2